# Duvida em método update PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte método para update

```
public function update($params, $id)
{
    $params_fields = "`".implode("`= ?, `", array_keys($params))."`= ?";
    $query  = "UPDATE `{$this->table}` SET {$params_fields}, WHERE `id`=:id";
    $stmt   = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);

    // Aqui esta a dúvida
    $stmt->bindValue(?,$value);

    //$stmt->execute();
    return $query;
}
```

Recebo $params dinamicamente de um array, como posso percorrer este array fazendo com que ele preencha o bindValue de acordo com o array recebido Ex:

```
for, while ou foreach{
    // resultado...
    $stmt->bindValue(1,$value);
    $stmt->bindValue(2,$value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa pegar os valores e preencher no lugar no `$value` ? Tente assim:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$array = array('valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3');

foreach($array as $valores){

    $stmt->bindValue($i, $valores);
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Opa legal cara, vlws ae ajudou não estava entendendo a logica para fazer essa parada ai.. fiz algumas alterações aqui e deu certinho vlw!